# Accessing Json Object : Node-Red

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-red

I am using Node-Red to count the number of people. For this purpose, I have designed a flow which is successfully detecting faces using visual recognition node. I have attached the output of Visual Recognition node from Debug window.

Debug Window Output:

```
msg : Object

  object
  _msgid: "dca9625c.8e531"
  topic: ""
     payload: buffer[117939]
     filename: "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/public/campi/image1.jpg"
     headers: object
     result: object
      images: array[1]
       0: object
         faces: array[3]
         image: "11734-1409-1shmx8t.yjcfu07ldi.jpg"
         images_processed: 1
```

I intend to count faces.

For Example:
I have counted the attributes of my SensorTag by the following command.

To Get Count:

```
 var count = {};
 count = Object.keys(msg.payload.d).length;
 return {payload:count};
```

Sensor Output:

```
 msg.payload : Object
 object
  d: object
    myName: "ti-sensortag2"
    ambientTemp: "31.50"
    objectTemp: "25.41"
    humidity: "43.93988"
    pressure: "1017.73"
    altitude: "-0.08634908"
```

I have received correct answer. i.e. 6 in above case.

For facial recognition, I don't know how to extract desired info. that is the total number of faces. Can you please provide an insight into this?

Regards,

Hamza

Comment: As I mentioned in the slack channel, find a javascript tutorial about working with JSON objects and arrays and have a go. We will not write this for you, you have to try first

Comment: ahh, the old "image of a console output" but this time, not even a screen capture, but a photo of a screen taken by a camera - how do you expect anyone to help if you can't even be bothered typing anything

Comment: I am studying tutorials and working over it. I will share my working asap.

Comment: I apologise for the photograph. I can't access the IP on which this Flow was created right now. I will edit the post when I have access to node-red flow.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks a lot for your advice. Without your direction I would not have learnt about json objects. Much appreciated!. may I request you to review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a documentation from this forum, I have wrote the following to fetch desired result.

```
 var count = {}; 

 count = Object.keys(msg.result.images[0].faces).length;

 return {payload:count};
```

Output:

```
msg : Object
object
 payload: 3
 _msgid: "dca9625c.8e531"
```

Comment: nearly, no need for the `Object.keys()` as `faces` is an array so you can just query it's length directly:  `msg.result.images[0].faces.length`